# can't paste from clipboard on Flutter Quill

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, quill

whenever i try to copy a texts into my flutter quill editor on my mobile phone but i keep getting error.
This is the code below

```
quill.QuillController _controller = quill.QuillController.basic();

class EditorView extends StatelessWidget {
  const EditorView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    return BlocConsumer<CreateRewritePostCubit, CreateRewritePostState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Editors Page')),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(14, 31, 14, 14),
                child: quill.QuillToolbar.basic(
                  controller: _controller,
                  dialogTheme: quill.QuillDialogTheme(
                    inputTextStyle: theme.textTheme.headline2,
                  ),
                  iconTheme: quill.QuillIconTheme(
                    iconSelectedFillColor: theme.colorScheme.primary,
                    borderRadius: 7,
                  ),
                  showCameraButton: false,
                  showImageButton: false,
                  showLink: false,
                  showFontSize: false,
                  showVideoButton: false,
                  showColorButton: false,
                  showBackgroundColorButton: false,
                  showAlignmentButtons: true,
                  showClearFormat: false,
                  showListCheck: false,
                  showIndent: false,
                  showUnderLineButton: false,
                  showLeftAlignment: false,
                  showRightAlignment: false,
                  showCenterAlignment: false,
                  showJustifyAlignment: false,
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0, left: 8.0, top: 3),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      final delta = _controller.document.toDelta();
                      final deltaData = DeltaToMarkdown();
                      final markDown = deltaData.convert(delta);
                      if (!_controller.document.isEmpty()) {
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Post',
                      style: theme.textTheme.headline2,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: theme.colorScheme.secondary,
                          offset: const Offset(5.0, 5.0),
                          blurRadius: 10,
                          spreadRadius: 2,
                        ),
                        const BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: quill.QuillEditor.basic(
                            controller: _controller,
                            readOnly: false,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

it gives me a PlatformException with

```
code:"error", details: null, and message:"Not supported, use openfile",
stacktrace: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported, use openfile
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:172)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:153)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:781)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1986)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1924)
    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin.getClipboardData(PlatformPlugin.java:479)
    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin.access$900(PlatformPlugin.java:30)
    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin$1.getClipboardData(PlatformPlugin.java:119)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformChannel.java:158)
    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1139)
```

i think it has something to do with the flutter internal clipboard package and the flutter quill package but i dont know what i am looking for.

```
Clipboard.getData (c:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\services\clipboard.dart:54)
<asynchronous gap> (Unknown Source:0)
RawEditorState.pasteText (c:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_quill-5.3.0\lib\src\widgets\raw_editor.dart:1015)
<asynchronous gap> (Unknown Source:0)
```

Comment: I have used flutter quill, copy paste worked fine for me. Sometimes emulators have issue with clipboard, have you tried on real device?

Comment: it's on a real device. it copied and paste when i tried it on windows but when i tried it on my andriod phone it gave those error.

Comment: What is the version of flutter quill you are using?

Comment: Flutter_quill: ^5.0.4

Comment: which version are you using? @SankethB.K

Comment: i am using 4.1.8